# How to recalculate private data hash from Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need to recompute the hash of private data to proof the integrity of the data. When private data collections are used the private data are stored in SideDBs and the hash of the data on the ledger according to the documentation. Basically the question splits up into two subquestions:

- How to access the hash of the private data?
- Which method to use to recompute the hash that is saved on the ledger?

Thanks in advance.

I use Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.2 with private data. I followed marbles example.

I expect to be able to calculate the private data hash and verify that it corresponds to the hash saved in the ledger.

Comment: Hi, i encounter the same problem. Did you manage to make it work on your side?

Answer (score 3):

to get the SHA256 hash (using Fabric 1.4.x contract API) use:

```
let pdHashBytes = await ctx.stub.getPrivateDataHash(collectionA, readKey);
let actual_hash = pdHashBytes.toString('hex');
```

You can calculate the private data written on Ubuntu like shown below.

`echo -n "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"quantity\":999}" |shasum -a 256`

and verify they match. So that's the mechanics of using private data method and verify patterns. Now lets add information about salting mechanics, as mentioned elsewhere in this post.

For most uses of private data, you'll most likely use a random salt so the private data cannot be brute force attacked in the permissioned blockchain network (between agreed parties). The salt is passed along in the same transient field as the private data. And (later on), it will need to be included with the private data itself, when recalculating the private data hash. See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data-arch.html#protecting-private-data-content

Comment: Just a comment. 

One should be careful with JSON payloads. One often creates an object and converts it to JSON string e.g. with JSON.stringify in Node.js to write it to the ledger. However, many of these functions do not guarantee the order of attributes in the final string. At the end one may get different strings for one and the same object and hence different hashes (one calculated manually and one in the ledger).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it, private data is security hole.

It amazes me that nobody had mentioned this before so I guess I better point this out now before more damages are being done.

The logic behind Privated data is simple, it puts data in a local embedded data store and puts a hash of that data on Blockchain.

The issue is that cryptographic hash is not an encryption mechanism, same data hashed by anyone using the same hashing algorithm (which is also very standardized) will always get the same hash! This is exactly what hash functions are designed for, and that’s why we use hash in digital signature to allow anyone to validate signed data.

However, this also means anyone can “decrypt” the data behind the hash by using dictionary attack.

Hashing is cheap, the cost of each hash on a normal laptop CPU core is about 3 microseconds, basically I can create 1 billion candidate hashes within one hour on a single laptop CPU core, and compare them to the hashes on Hyperledger Fabric DLT.

And I am just talking about using a single core on my laptop, not even 50% power of my laptop

Why is it dangerous? Because if an attacker is connected to a Blockchain system, the attacker knows the range of the data being hashed (etc, trade ID, item name, bank name, address, cell phone number), so you can easily create dictionary attack to get the true data behind the hash out.

How about adding salt to each data to be hashed? Well, that’s one thing Hyperledger Fabric didn’t do.

To their defense, Hyperledger didn’t implement salt because it is difficult to pass salts to counter parties. You can’t use DLT to pass salt value because attackers would see it, so you have to create another P2P connection with counter party. If you need to create connection with all the counter parties, what’s the point of using Blockchain in the first place?

It’s just scary that so many people are using this security whole.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know it could be dangerous, but it's for study.